# jqGrid : exporting 'formatted' data

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, export-to-excel, export-to-csv

**Objective**: To export data displayed in jqGrid as CSV maintaining existing formatting.  Make a generic utility to be used across multiple webpages using jqGrid for exporting data.

Thanks to excellent questions posted for exporting data before, I am able to create a csv formatted data from jqgrid and pass it to backend to be saved as .csv file.

**Steps Taken**:

- Used `jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data')` to get all row data
- Used `jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colNames')` to get colnames
- Created a tab separated output- No issues.

**Problem**: Since I used `'data'`, the column values are the raw values and not the formatted values.
For eg, from backend the date comes as a long -`1411674947000` but using custom formatter in jqgrid it displays as `2014-09-25 19:55:47`.

Similarly there are error codes which come as numeric values but formatted to show some text.
The objective is to use the formatted value eg '2014-09-25 19:55:47' in the csv output instead of '1411674947000'.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly how the data becomes a CSV - but before you export the data, you could use Javascript's `toUTCString()` function to convert the timestamps into human-readable strings:

```
var oldDate = new Date(1411674947000);
var newDate = oldDate.toUTCString();
console.log(newDate); // Thu, 25 Sep 2014 19:55:47 GMT
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/un9uc0s9/).